# What can you raise $x$ to in order for it to be equivalent to $\ln(x)$?

Tags: logarithms

Take, for example, $\frac{\ln(x)}{x^5}$. Can this be simplified into $x^n$?

If there exists an answer, can it be generified to work for $\log_n x$ where $n$ is $(0, \infty]$?

If it can't be, why not?

Comment: You can't.  Log is not a power function.  In particular, it grows more slowly than any power function, and it outputs negative values for inputs between $0$ and $1$, which power functions never do.

Comment: @NateEldredge:  I think that should be an answer.  I would upvote it.  I suspect the equivalence is for large $x$, so the point about negative values is not important, but OP did not define equivalent.

Comment: You should say $\text{“}n$ is in $(0,\infty]\text{''}$ rather than $\text{“}n$ is $(0,\infty].\text{''} \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots$or better yet, say $\text{“for } n\in(0,\infty].\text{''}$ That avoids the use of "where" as, in effect, a quantifier. The word "where" in this context should be used for establishing notation or conventions, such as "where $a=\text{longitude},$" etc. $\qquad$

Comment: So nitpicky $\space$

Answer (score 4):

$$x^A=\ln x \implies A \ln x=\ln(\ln x) \implies A=\frac{\ln(\ln x)}{\ln x}$$
Yes, it can be generalized to $\log_n(x)$, where the base $n \in  (0, 1) \cup (1,\infty)$. Further, if $n \in (0,1)$, then $x$ should also in in $(0,1)$.
Similarly, if $n \in (1, \infty)$ so should be $x \in (1,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh! sorry $n$ cannot be 1, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Note that this makes the exponent a function of $x$, so it seems a safe bet that this will not do what OP wanted it to do.

Comment: Whatever is possible has been stated.

Comment: Yes, there is sufficient information here for OP to decide whether the idea in the question is useful, so indeed this could be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for $n$ to be a constant, then this is impossible.  There is no constant value of $n$ such that $\frac{\ln x}{x^5} = x^n$ for every $x$.  The logarithm function simply isn't a power function.

You can get a pretty good sense of this if you graph them both for various values of $n$.  You'll see that they are never even close to being the same function.

Algebraically, maybe the simplest way to prove this is to just see what happens when $x=1$.  Then $\frac{\ln 1}{1^5} = 0$, while $1^n = 1$ no matter what $n$ is.

If $n$ is allowed to depend on $x$, then you can do it for all $x \ne 1$ as in Zafar Ahmed's answer.  However, as Zafar notes it still doesn't work for $x=1$.